# What happened to the flash messages in Rails 3.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use this code to display flash messages in Rails 3.2.1 apps (well, I did):

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
        <%= msg %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But I get nothing.  So I put `<%= debug flash %>` to see what I was getting back after an update and I get this:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
used: !ruby/object:Set
  hash: {}
closed: false
flashes: {}
now:
```

How to I do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I use for displaying flash messages and alerts is:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

But if your flash hash is empty, it's not going to display anything. Are you sure you're setting your flash hash properly?

Comment: This is exactly how I was doing it.  I later found out that there was a problem with a controller that was causing it to not render.  Other controllers worked fine.